# "This commit is missing author information"

Tags: github

I've just started using Github, but all of my commits show up as "blah [name]" where name *isn't* my Github username. Also, the latest commit shown at the top left corner says "Oops! This commit is missing author information".

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your git config first and see what values are set for `user.name` and `user.email`

```
git config -l
```

These two need to be the same as your username and email at Github.

To set these values just do the following

```
git config user.name "John Doe"
git config user.email "john.doe@example.com"
```

The commands above set your username and email for that specific repository. If you want to set them globally you can do:

```
git config --global user.name "Chris"
git config --global user.email "chris@personal.dev"
```